VHDL PWM Duty-Cycle Up/Down counting
I am trying to add more functionality to my simple VHDL program.
The basis of the program is to generate a PWM and increase the duty-cycle by some fixed steps. My program will now increase the duty-cycle until it reaches the maximum duty-cycle, and then it starts over.
I have for some time tried to make it count down when the PWM duty cycle reaches it maximum.
I have added a process (PWM_end_proc) that should control the UP/DOWN counting, but with no success. When I run my synthesis, it gets a latch warning:

[Synth 8-327] inferring latch for variable 'pwm_target_count_up_reg'

I try to get my head around this and especially about the latch thing, understanding that all cases for an signal assignment inside a process should be handled.
Now my proposed code is using IF statements.  I have also tried with a CASE statement and with the CLK in the sensitivity list.
Some hint/help would be appreciated.
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity PWM_Counter_2 is
    Generic (
        INPUT_CLK           : integer :=100000000;   --100 MHz
        PWM_FREQ            : integer := 50;          --PWM frequency 50 Hz
        PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP : integer := 100);
        
    Port ( 
        Pwm_Out     : out std_logic;
        Debug       : out std_logic;
        Clk         : in std_logic;
        Reset       : in std_logic);

end PWM_Counter_2;

architecture Behavioral of PWM_Counter_2 is

--Constants
constant FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX   : integer := INPUT_CLK/PWM_FREQ;    --Initialize frequency counts based on input clock frequency and wanted PWM frequency
constant PWM_STEP               : integer := FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX/PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP;

--Signal
signal pwm_value             : std_logic := '0';                            --Signal to hold pwm_value
signal debug_value           : std_logic := '0';
signal counter               : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX := 0; --Frequency counter
signal pwm_target            : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX :=0;    --Contain the duty cycle target value for the counter
signal pwm_counter           : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX :=0;
signal period_end            : std_logic := '0';
signal pwm_target_count_up   : boolean := false;

begin

Pwm_Out <= pwm_value;
Debug <= debug_value;

       Periode_end : process(counter)
       begin
           if(counter = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
               period_end <= '1';
           else
               period_end <= '0';
           end if;
       end process;

       Count_proc : process(Clk,Reset)
       begin
            if (Reset = '1') then
                counter <= 0;
            else
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                    if ( period_end = '1') then
                        counter <= 0;
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
       end process;

       PWM_target_proc : process(Clk,Reset)
       begin
            if (Reset = '1') then
                pwm_counter <= 0;
                pwm_target <= 0;
            else
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                   if ( period_end = '1') then
                       if (pwm_target = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
                            if (pwm_target_count_up = true) then
                                pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;
                                pwm_target <= Pwm_counter*PWM_STEP;
                            else 
                                pwm_counter <= pwm_counter - 1;
                                pwm_target <= Pwm_counter*PWM_STEP;
                            end if;
                       end if;
                   end if;
                end if;        
           end if;
       end process;
        
       PWM_output : process(counter, pwm_target)
       begin 
           if (counter < pwm_target) then
               pwm_value <= '1';
               debug_value <= '1';
           else
               pwm_value <= '0';
               debug_value<= '0';
           end if;
       end process;
       
       PWM_end_proc : process(pwm_target,pwm_target_count_up)
       begin
                if (pwm_target = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
                    pwm_target_count_up <= false;
                elsif (pwm_target = 0) then
                    pwm_target_count_up <= true;
                else
                    pwm_target_count_up <= pwm_target_count_up;
                end if;
       end process;
       
end Behavioral;


Do realise that you have a circuit design, not a program. Programs run on CPUs, which you don't have. Instead, descriptor language VHDL describes a digital logic circuit and it's a such an important distinction to make. Some people mistakenly try to write computer programs in VHDL, confusing processes for software processes/tasks and create a right mess. VHDL is more like a netlist from a schematic but a very high-level one. With a circuit, you design circuitry first then draw the schematic of it. It's the same with successful VHDL: you design a digital logic circuit then implement it in VHDL.

So best to (a) get your synchronous logic circuit clear with pencil and paper, and only then (b) try to implement that circuit in VHDL. At your starting level, it'll give you the best chance of a successful circuit design. Where possible, use combinatorial statements instead of processes, it'll keep it clearer for you.

@TonyM: Yes you are right and I see the need to step-back and look into some of the other suggestions, like going into RTL design.

So glad you look at it like that - you'll give yourself the best chance of understanding VHDL thoroughly and producing successful VHDL designs, making your life easier :-) What you're trying to design is very straightforward, as you probably imagined.

Just to understand your requirement: you want the PWM to increase duty cycle to max (1 step per PWM cycle), then decrease to minimum, repeating endlessly?

@TonyM Yep exactly. I have made an variable where I can set the step-size.

The problematic line in the PWM_end_proc process is this:
                pwm_target_count_up <= pwm_target_count_up;

You are trying to model combinational logic in the process, but that line implies that you want to retain state.
Synthesis tools require specific VHDL coding patterns, but your code does not adhere to any conventional pattern.  The tool assumes you are modeling a latch (which is a type of device that retains state).
Perhaps you can consider re-designing your logic to model the UP/DOWN counting with a flip-flop, similar to other flip-flops in your design:
process(Clk, Reset)


I see your point. I am still new to this, so could you give a hint as how to do it with a flip-flop?

Ok. So by using the Clk and Reset in the: “PWM_end_proc” process, I should be able to make this work?

@Tyassin: It's not that simple.  As I mentioned in the answer, you need to re-design the up/down logic.  Think about how your schematic diagram would look, then proceed from there.

Since you've developed your solution yourself and posted it, I can now post a solution without having given you the answer. Guiding yourself to the answer will teach you more, as it has done for all of us, and you've done a great job of that but I thought this solution might give you examples of good design practice, albeit in one process.
I haven't synthesised it but it simulates fine in Questa under a simple testbench. Always simulate VHDL to fully debug it before compiling it, even the simplest of designs.
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;




entity PWM_COUNTER_2 is
  generic(
    G_INPUT_CLK_HZ                : natural := 100e6;
    G_PWM_FREQ_HZ                 : natural :=  50;
    G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP         : natural := 100
  );
  port(
    CLK                           : in  std_logic;
    RST                           : in  std_logic;
    DEBUG                         : out std_logic;
    PWM                           : out std_logic
  );
end entity PWM_COUNTER_2;




architecture RTL of PWM_COUNTER_2 is


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Constant declarations.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  constant kInitPWMPrescaler      : natural
                                  := (G_INPUT_CLK_HZ / (G_PWM_FREQ_HZ * G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP)) - 1;

  constant kPWMStepCtrMax         : natural := G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP - 1;


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Signal declarations.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  signal tickPWM                  : std_logic;
  signal pwmPrescalingCtr         : natural range 0 to kInitPWMPrescaler;
  signal pwmCtr                   : natural range 0 to kPWMStepCtrMax;
  signal incPWM                   : std_logic;
  signal pwmDuty                  : natural range 0 to G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP;


begin


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- pPWM.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  pPWM : process(RST, CLK) is
  begin
    if (RST = '1') then
      tickPWM             <=  '0';
      pwmPrescalingCtr    <=   0 ;
      pwmCtr              <=   0 ;
      incPWM              <=  '1';
      pwmDuty             <=   0 ;
      PWM                 <=  '0';

    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then

      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Produce the 'tick' to step the PWM along.
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if (pwmPrescalingCtr = 0) then
        tickPWM           <=  '1';
        pwmPrescalingCtr  <=  kInitPWMPrescaler;
      else
        tickPWM           <=  '0';
        pwmPrescalingCtr  <=  pwmPrescalingCtr - 1;
      end if;

      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Run the PWM step counter.
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if (tickPWM = '1') then

        if (pwmCtr = kPWMStepCtrMax) then
          pwmCtr          <=  0;
        else
          pwmCtr          <=  pwmCtr + 1;
        end if;

      end if;

      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Modify the PWM duty cycle, endlessly bouncing it between the minimum and maximum limits.
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if (tickPWM = '1' and pwmCtr = 0) then

        if    (incPWM = '1' and pwmDuty = G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP) then
          incPWM          <=  '0';
          pwmDuty         <=  G_PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP - 1;

        elsif (incPWM = '1') then
          pwmDuty         <=  pwmDuty + 1;

        elsif (incPWM = '0' and pwmDuty = 0) then
          incPWM          <=  '1';
          pwmDuty         <=   1 ;

        elsif (incPWM = '0') then
          pwmDuty         <=  pwmDuty - 1;

        end if;

      end if;

      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Produce the final PWM waveform.
      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if (pwmCtr < pwmDuty) then
        PWM               <=  '1';
      else
        PWM               <=  '0';
      end if;

    end if;
  end process pPWM;


  DEBUG  <=  '0';


end architecture RTL;


With the advise from @toolic, @devnull and @TonyM, I gave it a last shot and implemented the counting with a synchronous process controlled by the Clk.
I looks very nice on my hardware adjusting the duty-cycle up and down in a steady count dictated by PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP.
BUT i will look into some more theory and understand why doing the process with Clk works better than with pwm_target. I am also pretty sure it is not the nicest looking VHDL code to solve this simple feature.
It also gives this warning

[Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (pwm_target_reg[47]) is unused and
will be removed from module PWM_Counter_2.

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity PWM_Counter_2 is
    Generic (
        INPUT_CLK           : integer :=100000000;   --100 MHz
        PWM_FREQ            : integer := 50;          --PWM frequency 50 Hz
        PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP : integer := 1000);
        
    Port ( 
        Pwm_Out     : out std_logic;
        Debug       : out std_logic;
        Clk         : in std_logic;
        Reset       : in std_logic);

end PWM_Counter_2;

architecture Behavioral of PWM_Counter_2 is

--Constants
constant FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX   : integer := INPUT_CLK/PWM_FREQ;    --Initialize frequency counts based on input clock frequency and wanted PWM frequency
constant PWM_STEP               : integer := FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX/PWM_DUTY_CYCLE_STEP;

--Signal
signal pwm_value             : std_logic := '0';                            --Signal to hold pwm_value
signal debug_value           : std_logic := '0';
signal counter               : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX := 0; --Frequency counter
signal pwm_target            : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX :=0;    --Contain the duty cycle target value for the counter
signal pwm_counter           : integer range 0 to FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX :=0;
signal period_end            : std_logic := '0';
signal pwm_target_count_up   : boolean := true;

begin

Pwm_Out <= pwm_value;
Debug <= debug_value;

       Periode_end : process(counter)
       begin
           if(counter = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
               period_end <= '1';
           else
               period_end <= '0';
           end if;
       end process;

       Count_proc : process(Clk,Reset)
       begin
            if (Reset = '1') then
                counter <= 0;
            else
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                    if ( period_end = '1') then
                        counter <= 0;
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
       end process;

       PWM_target_proc : process(Clk,Reset)
       begin
            if (Reset = '1') then
                pwm_counter <= 0;
                pwm_target <= 0;
            else
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                   if ( period_end = '1') then
                       if (pwm_target_count_up = false) then
                            pwm_counter <= pwm_counter -1;
                            pwm_target <= Pwm_counter*PWM_STEP;
                        elsif (pwm_target_count_up = true) then
                            pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;
                            pwm_target <= Pwm_counter*PWM_STEP;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;        
       end process;
        
       PWM_output : process(counter, pwm_target)
       begin 
           if (counter < pwm_target) then
               pwm_value <= '1';
               debug_value <= '1';
           else
               pwm_value <= '0';
               debug_value<= '0';
           end if;
       end process;
       
       PWM_end : process(Clk, Reset)
       begin
            if rising_edge(Clk) then
                if (pwm_target = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
                    pwm_target_count_up <= false;
                elsif (pwm_target = 0) then
                    pwm_target_count_up <= true;
                end if;
            end if;
       end process;
       
end Behavioral;


It is great that you persisted, found a solution and posted an answer.

Have you taken a look at the design I posted or tried it out?

@TonyM: Thx...Yes I have just tried it out and it works perfectly. I will take a closer look at the code and get the full understanding of the code. Something like a signal that is a "natrual" is new to me ;-)
I think, without have done it yet, that making it in a single process is intuatively easier for me to understand. But I forced myself to split it up, so as to break it down into smaller blocks and implement these.

The warning mentions a variable. Was this code implemented to get rid of the warning?
PWM_end_proc : process(pwm_target,pwm_target_count_up)
begin
    if (pwm_target = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
        pwm_target_count_up <= false;
    elsif (pwm_target = 0) then
        pwm_target_count_up <= true;
    else -- memory is inferred here:
        pwm_target_count_up <= pwm_target_count_up;
    end if;
end process;

This code explicitly tells the synthesis process to infer memory. The design mixes combinational logic, synchronous storage and latches. If you split the design between synchronous and combinational blocks, it will be simple to understand and analyze.

I have also tried with a CASE statement and with the CLK in the sensitivity list.

The sensitivity list doesn't affect synthesis, but a wrong one may create a mismatch between hardware and simulation. Please follow @toolic suggestion. Design a digital circuit with synchronous storage only (VHDL is only a way to describe it, but "thinking in digital circuits" is needed).

"I thought would be possible"

It is possible but since it is not frequently a good design approach the synthesis tool give you a warning just to be sure that's really what you wanted. Here is an analogy in other situation which is certainly familiar: a program written in C. If you write something like:
if (x = 0)
    // do stuff

The compiler would probably give a warning just to sure you didn't want a comparison instead of an assignment. It is like: "this is valid C, but are you sure that this is what you want?". One way of saying "I know what I'm doing" is just adding extra ()s.
That line in VHDL is a way of saying "I know what a latch is, and it is exactly what I want".
RTL (Register-Transfer Level) design may be a good investment before you proceed in the VHDL journey.

Yes exactly. I added that line to get rid of the warning with no luck. I can see that it introduce some kind of memory, which I thought would be possible. I will look into @toolic suggestion.

Yes you have mentioned it a few times now, to go into the RTL design :-) and I can see I run into these obstacles again and again. Are there any resources you could recommend?

I'm glad you made this decision. I'm not the only one trying to make the word "program" disappear from VHDL context, right? The resource depends on background and goals. If you don't want to start from transistors, Vahid's "Digital Design" (Ch. 3 to 5) may be a starting point. The book (https://vangelogit.github.io/Free_Range_VHDL_10/free_range_vhdl.pdf) I mentioned is shorter and keeps references to digital logic. "Digital Systems" from Tocci et. al. starts from scratch and stays at the component level. As your projects become more complex, the "programming" logic will simply not work.
